# mysqli_result does not seem to implement Iterator interface

Tags: php, mysqli, iterator

The [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) state that from version 5.4 and onwards:

> [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) support was added, as **mysqli_result** now implements [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php).

This means that `mysqli_result` must have implemented the Iterator methods `current()`, `key()`, `next()`, `rewind()` and `valid()`.

But when I do this:

```
/** @var \mysqli */
$rStmt = $oMySQLi->prepare('<valid query>');
$rStmt->execute();
/** @var \mysqli_result */
$rRes = $rStmt->get_result();
$rRes->rewind();
```

I get the error:

> Call to undefined method mysqli_result::rewind()

?!

Comment: `foreach` indeed works. My guess is that, since it isn't a userland implementation in PHP but an internal implementation in C, the methods are not really exposed to userland code. (Just a guess, though.)

Comment: [mysqli_result implements Traversable, not Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php). The docs are misleading.

Comment: About [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) the docs mention : *"Abstract base interface that **cannot be implemented alone**. Instead it **must be implemented by** either IteratorAggregate or **Iterator**."* That would mean either `mysqli_result` is not correctly implementing an interator, or the docs are wrong. What's the use of implementing an iterator if you can not call its functions? The contract imposed by the promise of the implementation is broken.

Comment: @Code4R7 Nothing is broken. The documentation say that the class is implementing the `Traversable` interface, which it does. Keep in mind that this interface does not define the `rewind()` method, so the `mysqli_result` class is not required to implement this method (which it doesn't). Also notice the note on the documentation saying that internal classes don't need to implement the other interfaces like `Iterator`. They can be used in `foreach` directly.

Comment: Ah, now i see, the documentation is not just misleading, it contradicts **itself**, because both statements can not be logically true at the same time. So, instead of actually implementing the `Iterator` interface in full on `mysqli_result`, developers now have to reïmplement the mysqli_result iterator themselves over and over again with an `IteratorIterator`... hopefully things like these will improve with PHP 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mysqli_result does implement the Iterator functions, they are just not exposed to userland ([source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqli/mysqli_result_iterator.c)). You can, however, wrap mysqli_result in an [IteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoriterator.php).

```
$it = new \IteratorIterator($result);
$it->current(); // or rewind(), next()
```

IteratorIterator directly uses the C implementation and is therefore not limited to userland accessibility restrictions.